# Unity Camera frustum mapping to physical camera

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, matrix, camera, augmented-reality

I am currently working on a custom AR solution that does not use any of the existing plugins on Unity. I have written my own native android library for Unity, which does image recognition and pose estimation. We are trying to pass the pose to the Unity application.

However, to do that, I have to fist map the camera frustum of the Unity camera, to that of the physical camera of the device. My question is, do we have to change the projectionMatrix in the Unity Camera to achieve this and calculate a new frutum. Would it not be enough to just change the FOV and aspect ratio of the camera? On trying to change the projection Matrix of the camera, I do not see the aspect ration changing automatically. Does the projection Matrix not dictate the aspect ratio of the camera?